# can't connect to ec2 tomcat localhost

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've followed a lot of tutorials and questions which been asked before, but still no good (I'm total beginner in ec2)

I've did the following:
lunched Amazon Linux AMI 2015.09.1 (HVM), SSD Volume Type.

```
sudo yum install tomcat8-webapps tomcat8-admin-webapps
sudo yum install tomcat8
sudo service tomcat8 start
```

I've added this rule to my security group inbound:

```
HTTP
TCP
80
0.0.0.0/0
```

but when I try to browse to:
Public DNS:8080

I get:

> This webpage is not available: ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

I expect to see the tomcat welcome page (as I go to localhost:8080) so I could deploy my war file.

what am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `Tomcat` itself if running, you need to add a `inbound TCP rule` for port 8080 in your *Security Groups* from AWS Console.
[image]

You may also check if Tomcat is running at port 8080 simply by issuing a

```
curl localhost:8080
```

*Note*: Only open necessary ports for public access because of security reasons.Tomcat GUI Manager also have to be enabled,**Do not use the default username/password of tomcat/tomcat.** Use a more secure password.

Comment: i get:
HTTP Status 404 - 
description The requested resource is not available.
Apache Tomcat/8.0.28


---- but when I "ps -ef | grep tomcat" it is there

Comment: Check if you can access it with this url  http://ec2_host:8080/manager/html
Also check from the tomcat log, that the `manager`  webapp is deployed successfully probably u can try restarting the Tomcat and cross check.

Comment: You saved my day Thanks

Answer (score 3):

First check:

```
$ netstat -lnt
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8005          :::*                    LISTEN
```

You need add tomcat parameters (catalina.sh):

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Addresses=true "
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this you need to configure load balancer in AWS and set port forwarding to local machine (external port (8080) -> internal port (8080)).